# When to use reflexive pronouns?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

I have been studying pronominal verbs in French which have three categories:

1. Reflexive verbs
2. Reciprocal verbs
3. Idiomatic pronomial verbs

However, I do not understand sentences such as "il m'a dit". The subject "il" does not agree with the reflexive pronoun "me"...

My questions are:

1. Why don't we write the above sentence as "il dit a moi"?
2. Can you please explain, when exactly one uses reflexive pronouns "me, te, se, nous, vous, se" in the French language?

Comment: Accusative, dative and reflexive pronouns are only distinguished in the third person: le, lui, se / la, lui, se / les, leur, se. For the other person, there's only form of the weak pronoun: "Il me disait courageux" (me: direct object pronoun); "Il me disait quelque chose" (me: indirect object pronoun); "Je me disais quelque chose" (me: reflexive pronoun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe take a look at these :

- https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/double-pronoun-order/
- https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/indirect-objects/
- https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/direct-objects/

As far as I know (as native speaker not specialist) it's not a reflexive pronoun here, but a direct/indirect object pronoun, that replace the object.

- indirect

  - Elles donnent à moi => elle me donnent
  - Nous donnons à elle => Nous lui donnons
- direct

  - Tu vois lui => tu le vois
  - J'emmène eux => je les emmène

French language uses these replacements when the object is a pronoun (don't know exactly why, just a rule learned at school ;) )

If other situations, you can say :

- Tu vois le bar
- Ils boivent des bières

But, it's also a trick not to repeat an object that you are talking about :

- La bière est servie. Tu la bois.
- and not : La bière est servie. Tu bois la bière.

Note that a reflective pronoun is often used with an object pronoun :

- Je m'envoie une lettre => Je me l'envoie
- Je donne une bière à lui => Je la lui donne

(In these two last examples, "bière" and "lettre" are already known in the discussion.)

Comment: Can you please explain to me why don't we say for example "j'aimes toi" instead of "je t'aimes" in French?

Comment: Don't have enough skills in linguistic to do that but wiki does ;) Look at this (in french) https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronom_personnel#Pronoms_personnels_compl%C3%A9ments
It's about "clitic" (i've learned a word today) : "A proclitic appears before its host.[2] It is common in Romance languages. For example, in French, there is "il s'est réveillé" ("he woke up"), or "je t'aime" ("I love you"). " [quoted from here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic]

Answer (score 0):

Si on dit

> Le fils de Pierre est arrivé. La femme de George est morte.

on ne dit jamais

> Le fils de lui est arrivé. La femme de lui est morte.

Un pronom personnel ne s'emploie pas comme complément d'un nom déterminé par l'article.
Il faut dire

> Son fils est arrivé. Sa femme est morte.

Le déterminant son s'appelle déterminant possessif. Il exprime un rapport de possession.

> C'est mon chapeau, ma valise; ton chapeau, ta valise; son chapeau; sa valise.

Son chapeau peut se traduire comme his hat or her hat.

> Ce sont mes chapeaux, mes valises; tes chapeaux, tes valises; ses
> chapeau; ses valises.
>
> C'est notre chapeau, notre valise; votre chapeau, votre valise; leur chapeau; leur valise.
>
> Ce sont nos chapeaux, nos valises; vos chapeaux, vos valises; leurs
> chapeau; leurs valises.

Pour bien distinguer on peut dire

> C'est son chapeau à lui (his hat). C'est son chapeau à elle (her hat).

On emploie mon, ton, son devant les noms ou les adjectifs commençant par une voyelle ou un h muet.

> Mon amie, son habitude, mon étrange mésaventure, ton heureuse copine.